# How to compare items in the gridview in flutter?

Tags: flutter, gridview

I have been trying to but can't figure quite how to create a gridview displaying items from a online strore and to be able to compare between two items that have been selected from a checkbox. Does anyone how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could overwrite the equality operator and hashcode for your GridView Item class.

- [Official Equality override documentation.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxShadow/operator_equals.html)

Then you can just compare those items via a typical `==` operator. Remember, always override hashCode property when overriding the `==` operator.

There's also a common library that is used to simplify this called [Equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable). The usage is pretty straight forward if you check the examples on pub.dev

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to the items from your online store, instead I used freely [available data](http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/api/characters) about Harry Potter Characters.

I used a gridview to display the data items. Once two items are selected a bottomsheet pops up showing the comparison.

Here is a [gif](https://i.imgur.com/cvPZ2nY.gif) of the working app, code can be found [here](https://github.com/vipinkashyap/flutter_grid_compare).

I used flutter_bloc to implement the bloc pattern to this app. All the logic is managed in CharacterBloc which responds to three events

1. Fetching data
2. Selecting characters
3. De-selecting characters